# Using the Strong Markov property, show
$Z_{t} := B_{t+\tau}-B_{\tau}$ is a Brownian motion and independent with $\mathcal F_{\tau}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

Strong Markov property states that for bounded jointly measurable process  $Y_s(\omega)$ on $ [0,\infty) \times \Omega$ and a stopping time $\tau$,

$$E^x(Y_{\tau} \circ \theta_{\tau})= \phi (B_{\tau}, \tau)$$ holds where $\phi(y,s) := E^y (Y_s)$ for $(y,s) \in \mathbb R \times [0, \infty)$ and $\theta_t (\omega):=\omega '$ with $\omega ' (s) := \omega(s+t)$. Note $E^y$ stands for the expectation w.r.t. Brwonian motion starting at $y  \in \mathbb R$ and $B_s$ stands for the Brownian motion.

> I want to show that, using the above Strong Markov property,
>   $$Z_{t} := B_{t+\tau}-B_{\tau}$$ is a Brownian motion and independent with $\mathcal F_{\tau}$, the sigma-algebra  associated with the stopping time $\tau$.

I have no idea where to start and only had some unsuccessful calculations by setting $Y_s(\omega)=\omega(t)-\omega(0)$ for a fixed $t\geq 0$ which is $B_t$ essentially.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/682157/36150)

Comment: @saz Thanks for the reference, but I would like tonuse the above form if its possible.

Comment: You were saying that you have no idea how to start. The linked question should give you some idea how to approach it.